# charset issue with calling aspell program using Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, exec, inputstream, aspell

I am trying to call linux aspell program for pt_BR spellchecking in Java using Java Runtime.getRuntime().exec(). The issue is that it seems something wroing with input/output char encoding. some input word is splitted into two words at accent letter position, and output is displayed with � for accent letters. I can see aspell can spell-check pt_BR correctly in command pipeline mode.  The code for setting up aspell is following:

```
String[] aspellCommand = new String[4];
            aspellCommand[0] = "aspell";
            aspellCommand[1] = "-a";
            aspellCommand[2] = "--keymapping=ispell";
            aspellCommand[3] = "--lang=pt_BR";
            String[] envArray = new String[0];

            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(aspellCommand, envArray);

            System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset()); /utf-8

            InputStreamReader ir = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream(), "utf-8");
            OutputStreamWriter or = new OutputStreamWriter(process.getOutputStream(), "utf-8");

            aspellOutputStream = new BufferedReader(ir);
            aspellInputStream = new PrintWriter(or,true);

            System.out.println(ir.getEncoding()); /utf-8
            System.out.println(or.getEncoding()); /utf-8
```

The code to feed input into aspell:

```
aspellInputStream.println(misSpelledWord);
```

The code to read from aspell:

```
String line = aspellOutputStream.readLine();
```

I suspect something wrong with IO stream charset encoding, but I don't know where exactly to set them.

Answer (score 1):

don't use Runtume.exec which is buggy. use ProcessBuilder instead. or https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec